# Python: var = var / 5 * 2 does not evaluate the same as var /= 5 * 2

Tags: python, operators, variable-assignment

I am new to Python and I can't figure this one out. I am sure it is something very simple that I am overlooking.

I am learning the compound assignment operators in Python and I learned that this expression:

var = var / 5 * 2

Can be written using the /= operator as:

var /= 5 * 2

Here is what I don't understand. If I set var = 20 and then solve this expression:

```
var = var / 5 * 2
var = 20 / 5 * 2
var = 4 * 2
var = 8
```

I get an answer of 8.

If I put 'var = var / 5 * 2' into IDLE, I do get 8 as the new value of var.

But, if I put var back to 20 and solve for this expression in IDLE:

var /= 5 * 2

I get an answer of 2.0 as the new value of var.

I can't understand why I get a different result when using the compound assignment operator?

If I set var = 20 and solved this expression:

```
var = var / (5 * 2)
var = 20 / (10)
var = 2.0
```

Then I get the same answer without using the compound assignment operator.

So, it seems the /= operator adds parenthesis to the expression by default. Is that what is happening? I can see that causing a lot of bugs if I don't understand how to use the compound assignment operator appropriately.

I would appreciate it if anyone could explain this to me. Thanks!

Comment: With the [augmented assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) the right-hand-side is evaluated first then the divide-equals is performed.

Comment: the compound does not add () around it - it does the wanted operation with all thats on the right hand side. If you want to divide by 5 then multiply by 2 do `var /= 5` followed by `var *= 2`. or do a `var *= 2/5` instead

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order .. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: When you see /= or += or -=... the operator there will be last executed

Comment: Got it. So it is not really just a simple conversion of your expression x = x <op> y to x <op>=y. You have to know the rules and you might need to re-write your expression to evaluate correctly. I guess in simple examples, it is just a simple conversion but with a more complex expression, you have to 'craft' the correct expression to ensure it evaluates correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var / 5 * 2
```

means

```
(var / 5) * 2
```

because the rules of arithmetic say so, and any other result would be incorrect.

Conversely,

```
var /= 5 * 2
```

means "divide `var` by the expression on the right and update `var`"
so it is equivalent to

```
var = var / (5 * 2)
```

and no other result would make sense.

If you expected those commands to evaluate differently, adjust your expectations, or always use parentheses to make sure the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here the point is about precedence of operators.
When you use var= var / 5 * 2 , then first division takes place then multiplication due to precedence. But when you use var/= 5 * 2 , precedence of * is higher than /= , therefore it is evaluated later and you get 2.0 as answer.
Just refer to precedence of operators once.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment

```
var /= 5 * 2
```

For `var=20` means that Python evaluates `var` to `20` in the left side, evaluates `5 * 2` to `10`in the right side, and then changes `var` in-place if possible (not possible here, it is an `int`) to `20/10`, that is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, bro
Check the operator precedence of the operators. Always the arithmetic operators like +,-,*,/,% have higher precedence than the compound operators. 
That is why, `var = 20 / 5 * 2 => 4*2=8.0` ('/' has higher precedence than *(asterisk)) and 
`var1=20,
var1 /=5*2 => 20/10=2.0`(asterisk has higher precedence than compound operators).

Hope you get it.

Check this: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html for info.